# Can I have use silverlight 4.0 with the visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Can I have use silverlight 4.0 with the visual studio 2008 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Upgrade. There still is Visual Studio 2010- for free if you go for the express edition.